# Best practise or tool for mocking backend fake API server?

Tags: api, mocking, backend

We are very new to frontend, `Node.js` etc. We are going to start our first frontend project with `Vue.js`(nuxt) and axios for backend api calls. So far, state of the art i guess.

Our backend team is also still in the planning phase, so our first thought was to setup a simple `Node.js` server for defining the API routes we need in the frontend and just return the json we expect from this endpoint. But before we start coding, we would like to know what are the best practices or maybe useful tools we should consider for building such a mock/fake (temporary) API? What is the best way for switching to the real backend API if the backend team completes a part of the needed endpoints, without to change a lot of code?

Comment: What about some online fake API tools? For instance https://quickmocker.com . No need to code anything, just define your endpoints with mock data. For the purpose of switching to the production API gradually, you may use proxy feature, which means there's no need to change or build anything in the app, just add proxy for specific endpoint, one by one as soon as it is ready, and go on. Obviously when the app testing phase is completed, you better change the URL inside the application and build it using production API.

Comment: You can use free trial of mock apis.
https://themockapis.in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it is very important to start with a correct setup to avoid struggling with unexpected use cases later that may result in refactoring of a lot of code. In case you start with a frontend that is based on an api without having an api, I recommend to you to avoid mocking a backend fake API yourself but use a already existing solution.

A very useful tool which i can hightly recommend for mocking a fake backend API, especially for beginners, is [jsonserver.io](https://www.jsonserver.io).

For later API url switch, I recommend to use .env for defining the API urls. The use of .env files requires the dotenv lib you can get from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). The use of dotenv allows you to define different .env files like a **.env.development** or **.env.production** or whatever you like. For loading the correct env you have just to do the following:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` })
```

This would load the .env based on the NODE_ENV (development/production).
The .env files can contain the vars which define the URLs you need for your backend like **BASE_API_URL**. If you decide to use e.g jsonserver.io, the **development** env would define

```
BASE_API_URL=https://api.jsonserver.io
```

and the **production** (or whatever you're going to name it for further non-production urls)

```
BASE_API_URL=https://your-domain.com
```

Finally you have to set base url in your axios configuration section at nuxt.config.js

```
axios: {
    browserBaseURL: process.env.BASE_API_URL,
    ....
}
```

Thats it, just adapt you NODE_ENV or your custom indicator which you want to use for the condition to load the right env file.

NOTE: If you use axios proxy, you have to define the API urls from env in your proxy configuration and use the base browser url as axios base url.